# Plotting data point in different clusters

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I have my data points and cluster number as follows:

```
X        Y       cluster
-0.42042 0.2071  0
-1.4986  -1.8658 0
-0.50905 -0.0751 0
2.1978   1.9568  1
1.4901   1.6177  1
1.6961   1.8293  1
1.6021   0.0857  1 
0.87831  0.71435 1
2.6688   1.3426  1
-1.741   0.90686 2
-1.8332  0.35599 2
-3.0733  0.42656 2
-2.1991  0.41843 2
-2.8099  0.93542 2
-1.3631  1.0914  2
```

The above data was unsorted, so I used `sortrows`  to sort in terms of cluster number and I get the above data.

I have to plot these clusters. Is there any MATLAB function for plotting clusters? I know we can use something like this: `plot(M(:,1), M(:,2), '.');`

But this plot all values in one cluster. I have to plot in three clusters as per data. The clusters  are 0, 1,2. So three clusters with three different colors should be plotted. So something like this:

[image]

Any idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

So you can do it in several ways:
You can use the current color map for the colors and simply :

```
scatter(x,y,'cdata',cluster,'marker','.');
```

or as you wrote in your code

```
scatter(M(:,1),M(:,2),'cdata',M(:,3),'marker','.');
```

you could also use a predefined color map instead of the default

```
ClusterColorMap=rand(max(M(:,3)),3); %random colormap
colormap(ClusterColorMap);
scatter(M(:,1),M(:,2),'cdata',M(:,3),'marker','.');
```

here `ClusterColorMap` would have 3 rows, each containing a specific color (in RGB format in the 3 columns chosen here as random).
if you know the number of clusters in advanced you can set this matrix to have specific values.

Comment: If I consider your second method, please explain how this will print three clusters, for each of 0, 1,2?

Comment: Got me there, had a typo in my code and added some explenations. bw, you could do something similar with plot but for scattered point data scatter() is supposed to be better

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to divide you data into three groups and plot them individually.
Something like this assuming you have three variables `X`, `Y`, and `cluster`:

```
grp1 = cluster==0;
grp2 = cluster==1;
grp3 = cluster==2;
```

Then plot each group individually:

```
plot(X(grp1),Y(grp1),'.', X(grp2),Y(grp2),'.', X(grp3),Y(grp3),'.')
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. How do we divide this data into three groups ?

Comment: @gpuguy  You divide the data into 3 groups as shown in the answer, using the `grp1`, `grp2` and `grp3` variables. Try the code and inspect the variables, it should become clear...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct way to do this:

```
gscatter(x,y,cluster)
```

Here is an example with your data:

[image: clusters]

and if you want to set the colors, symbols, etc...

```
gscatter(x,y,cluster,'cmk','p*^')
```

[image: cluster2]